# How to capture the error code in $q deferred promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest, angular-decorator

I have planned to create a custom alert message according to the error codes.
So I have to get the error codes while sending the request to the server and getting an response from the server.

500 - Some thing went wrong.
403- technical error occured;
401 - File not found.
400- unauthorized access:

In the application, I can capture the error code in `httpinterceptor` response 
but I am unable to capture the error code in the deferred promises.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run();
```

**controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run();

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.EmployeeList = [];
    myService.getData().then(function (data,status) {
        myCtrl.EmployeeList = data;
        console.log(status);
    }), (function (data, status) {
        if (status === 500) {
            toastr.warn("technical error occurred");
        }
        else if (status === 400) {

            toastr.warn("something went wrong");
        }
    });
}]);

var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var fact = {};
fact.getData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //$http.get('/Test/getData',


    $http.get('http://simpleApiEarl.azurewebsites.net/api/envelopes',
        {
            cache: true
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (typeof response.data === 'object')
            {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }
            else
            {
                debugger;
                deferred.reject(response.data);

                console.log("Error:" +response.status);
            }
        }, function (response, status) {

            console.log(response.status);
            deferred.reject(response.data,status);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}

return fact;
}]);
```

Working in the `interceptor`:

```
var interceptor = function ($q, $rootScope) {

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                console.log(config);
                return config;
            },

            response: function (response) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                return response || $q.when(response);
           },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status == 500)
                {

                    alert('Bad Request Processed');

                    return $q.reject(rejection);


                }


if(rejection.status == 403)

{
  alert('some thing went wrong');
}
            }
        }
    };

 $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```

**problem:**
Why am I not able to capture the error code in deferred promises's reject response?

Screenshot:

Before sending service call:

[image]

After rejection getting status as 0
[image]

In console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before your `deferred.reject(response.data, status)`, try to `console.log(response)`. Look into it in your code, and you should find your error code.

If you can, post a picture of your console log.

From what I see in your code, replace your conditions by this :

```
if(data.status == 500) toastr.warn("technical error occurred");
else if(data.status == 400) toastr.warn("something went wrong");
```

And in your service, stop sending back `response.data` :

```
deferred.reject(response,status);
```

Comment: i am getting an error code in httpinterceptors, but i am not getting in $q rejection error response. have updated the screenshot.

Comment: Ok I see it, now open every every object in `response`, such as `config`, `headers` ... And you have a CORS error, which means you did not set your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your backend. Do you know this error or not ?

Comment: i know the error,  i am putting that url for display error code .My question is not able to capture the error code in $q rejection, its shows status as 0, and for 403. that error code is able to capture in httpinterceptor,why i am not able to capture there.

Comment: I don't see your `httpInterceptor` anywhere. You forgot a header here. Since you have no response from the back-end, you will have neither data, nor error code.

Comment: Sorry , In httpInterceptor , am getting status as 0. But in another example am getting error in httpinterceptor, but not in deferred error .i will update the code after some time.

Comment: You need to understand that you must correct your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error before going further. Please correct it, and if you don't know how to, just tell me what your back-end is.

Comment: Ok, got it.  i have updated the second example there , Bad request comes but not able to capture in $q error rejection, getting in httpinterceptors responseError.

Comment: You don't understand do you. You need to **correct your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` before doing something else**

Comment: i can understand what you saying. I got the error code when i change the ` .error(function(response) as .error(function (status) `.Thanks for your valuable responses.

Comment: Changing the name of a function parameter won't give you a different error. If you really need help, please correct your CORS error, and I will be able to help you.